# Part of a do-while loop is repeating more than it should be. How do I fix this?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, repeat, do-while

I have a do while loop created and it is doing almost exactly what I want but part of it is repeating more than I want it to. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() // none of the above is included in the pdf version of this file but I put it in anyway.
{
int count = -1, number = 1, product = 1;
do
{   
    ++count;
    product = product * number;
    cout << "Enter an integer number to be included in the product " 
 << endl << "or enter 0 to end the input: "; // I put endl in this weird position just because I found it more readable lined up like this that is all.
    cin >> number;
}
while (number != 0);

if (count > 0)
{
    cout << endl << "The product is " << product << "." << endl;
}
}
```

The problem is that the "Enter an integer number to be included in the product or enter 0 to end the input is repeating after I input the numbers. It still gives me the correct answer but the cout still repeats when I don't want it to. I have tried fixing this many different ways (note: I AM very new to programming) but each one either makes the program no longer function or does not fix it in the first place.

The comments are directed at my teacher so sorry. Also sorry if this doesn't appear as actual code it's my first time posting anything here.

Comment: Works for me - what input are you using? What output do you see? Note that if you enter anything invalid (ie not an integer), your program will loop forever.

Comment: Why the whole "enter 0 to end the input" thing if you don't want it to repeat?

Answer (score 0):

The output "Enter an integer number to be included in the product or enter 0 to end the input:" will continue to be displayed until the user enters a 0. Because it is a DO while loop, it will run once and then check input each time. If the input is not a 0, it will run again.

If you want the user to enter a maximum number of inputs, you can change this line:
    `while(number != 0);`

to this:
    `while (number != 0 && count < {max subtracted by one});`

and change {max subtracted by one} to your desired maximum number of inputs minus one (because your counter starts at negative one).

For example, If you want a maximum of 10 numbers, you would change the line to:
    `while (number != 0 && count < 9);`

However, it should be pointed out that, because you evaluate the product BEFORE you accept input, the last number you enter will not be included in the evaluation. So you might want to change the code inside the do while loop to this:

```
++count;
cout << "Enter an integer number to be included in the product "  
<< endl << "or enter 0 to end the input: "; // I put endl in this weird position just because I found it more readable lined up like this that is all.

cin >> number;

if (number != 0) //This prevents multiplication by 0 when they type a 0
    product = product * number;
```